# Performance breakdown after putting an Rcpp function into an R package

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp, r-package

I want to speed up matrix multiplication in R by using the c++ Eigen library. 
Somehow my simple function `eigen_mult` performs very differently when put in a package.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_mult(Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A, Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X){
  return(A * X);
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
B <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "base R" =  A %*% B,
  "Eigen1" =  eigen_mult(A, B),
  "Eigen2" =  svmod::eigen_mult2(A,B), # exactly the same function but within a package
  times = 10
)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 base R  685.4485  744.8911  921.5104  878.4409 1040.7563 1405.5009    10
 Eigen1  173.9677  180.8769  201.6563  198.3676  218.2076  240.8219    10
 Eigen2 6495.3652 6533.3584 6937.0707 7031.7074 7135.5751 7292.6177    10
```

Why does this happen?  Here is the link to the function in the package https://github.com/alexandergerber/svmod/blob/master/src/utility.cpp

**Edit**

In my session Info I found that to the time it was working badly the package and `RcppEigen` were `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)`:

```
other attached packages:
[1] microbenchmark_1.4-6
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1      RcppEigen_0.3.3.4.0 Matrix_1.2-14       tools_3.5.1         yaml_2.2.0          Rcpp_0.12.19        svmod_0.1.0        
[8] grid_3.5.1          lattice_0.20-35
```

Whereas is session where it is working it looks like this:

```
other attached packages:
[1] svmod_0.1.0          microbenchmark_1.4-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  Matrix_1.2-14   tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.19    grid_3.5.1      lattice_0.20-35
```

I don't know how to reproduce the first session to check if this is the source of the problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove the namespace call, e.g. `svmod::`?

Comment: We don't know why it happens. Your best bet may to keep reducing the package, or start from an empty one.  There is not reason why this should happen.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I played arround a bit and it works fine with a clean R session. After some time it seems to get worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer (yet), but I want to note I do not get this behavior:

```
# Try using a new package from scratch, with only this function
Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("svmod", example_code = FALSE)
# Then add RcppEigen in LinkingTo, add eigen_mult.cpp to src/
Rcpp::compileAttributes("svmod")
devtools::install("svmod")
Rcpp::sourceCpp("eigen_mult.cpp")
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
B <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
microbenchmark(
    "base R" =  A %*% B,
    "Eigen1" =  eigen_mult(A, B),
    "Eigen2" =  svmod::eigen_mult(A,B),
    times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 base R 853.6304 858.1488 882.5745 871.6440 894.3132 938.8883    10   b
 Eigen1 172.4896 173.4745 174.5335 174.5249 175.4813 177.6152    10  a 
 Eigen2 170.9105 174.1170 174.7807 174.3971 176.5156 179.0742    10  a
```

```
# Try your package
remove.packages("svmod")
devtools::install_github("alexandergerber/svmod")
# (in a new R session)
Rcpp::sourceCpp("eigen_mult.cpp")
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
B <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
microbenchmark(
    "base R" =  A %*% B,
    "Eigen1" =  eigen_mult(A, B),
    "Eigen2" =  svmod::eigen_mult2(A,B),
    times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 base R 813.7922 820.6887 854.6929 837.3059 879.7640 978.0778    10   b
 Eigen1 171.8826 172.6738 210.6316 181.7109 246.6778 332.1725    10  a 
 Eigen2 171.7884 172.8768 176.0966 173.5973 177.5424 186.5957    10  a
```

Comment: As it should be. Laws of Physics still hold. News at 11pm.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Exactly

Comment: @Alex I'm sure that's true. The point here is that your issue does not have to do with placing your function in a package. It is something more idiosyncratic with your specific setup, which may take more tinkering to uncover, starting perhaps with Dirk's suggestion to begin with an empty package, add your function, then add things one at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now on my machine as well. I am still not sure what caused the problem, but I found something strange in the session were it did not work well (see  the edited question). However, I don't know how to reproduce this.

Comment: @Alex Interesting. I also notice in your new edit that `svmod_0.1.0` is attached in your second `sessionInfo()` and `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)` in your first. I haven't thought through the implications of that (it may be that this should be totally unrelated, I'm not sure), but something to note.